# Default pylintrc completely disables pylint

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint, pylintrc

All I want to do is use the `generated-members=` line to disable the false "no-members" errors for several packages.

So, in the VS Code terminal, in my project root directory, I run:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
```

**All** linting warnings immediately disappear, even before I've change anything in the rc file. The only way I've been able to bring them back is by deleting .pylintrc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to diagnose the problem and find a workaround. The issue was that the rcfile was being generated in the wrong encoding. Running `pylint mymodule` gave the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

as described [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1663).

I did not find a way to make pylint generate the config file in the correct encoding, but as a workaround, I just opened the .pylintrc file in Notepad++, changed the encoding to UTF-8 there, and then saved the file. After that, the .pylintrc file stays in the correct encoding even with subsequent edits in VS Code, allowing linting to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for my Windows PC.

I installed a Linux VM, where I configured PyCharm and Pylint. Then, I created a GitHub repository to upload .pylintrc file on the Linux VM. Finally, I downloaded on Windows the .pylintrc file from the repository and I specified the path to this file in the configuration of Pylint.

It worked, even after making changes to .pylintrc. The main bug I encountered was that sometimes (when running Pylint) it would use a previous version of .pylintrc, instead of the current one, but it can be fixed by restarting Pycharm.